# how to stop the typescript error `Property 'play' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.ts(2339)`

Tags: reactjs, typescript

H, I have this native javascript line in my React/typescript app and as first it was erroring that `Object is possibly 'null'.` so I have added the `!` between the selector method and the `play()` method, however, I got this error now saying `Property 'play' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.ts(2339`
How I can fix this with typeScript,m thanks

```
  const handleSound = () => {
    document.getElementById("helloMessage")!.play();
}
```

Comment: Does this solve your issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44099955/play-does-not-exist-on-type-htmlelement-and-property-value-does-not-exist

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the `null` issue with an `if`.

Casting will fix the `play does not exist` error

```
const handleSound = () => {
  const element = document.getElementById("helloMessage") as HTMLVideoElement;
  if (!element) {
    throw new Error('Missing element')
  }
  element.play();
}
```

Also, you should never use `getElementById` in React